# Prestashop 1.6 : updating version Bootstrap

Tags: prestashop-1.6, bootstrap-sass

I'm working in Prestashop 1.6 and I notice that it using the Bootstrap version 3.0.0 and I would like to update at the last version 3.3.4.

How should I do this?

Do I need to update manually the folder bootstrap_lib?

(I use Mac OSX and the terminal)